# Internal Server Error for Deshboard only mode user

Tags: elastic-stack, kibana-7

I have created dashboard and shared it to other computer which is demo user with  the role-> kibana_dashboard_only_user. 
now when i open shared with demo user login credentials it shows error like

```
Internal Server Error

Error: Internal Server Error
      SearchError@http://10.42.35.14:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js:3:298201
_callee2$/<.searching</<@http://10.42.35.14:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js:4:324908
processQueue@http://10.42.35.14:5601/built_assets/dlls/vendors.bundle.dll.js:427:199687
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://10.42.35.14:5601/built_assets/dlls/vendors.bundle.dll.js:427:200650
$digest@http://10.42.35.14:5601/built_assets/dlls/vendors.bundle.dll.js:427:210412
$apply@http://10.42.35.14:5601/built_assets/dlls/vendors.bundle.dll.js:427:213219
done@http://10.42.35.14:5601/built_assets/dlls/vendors.bundle.dll.js:427:132717
completeRequest@http://10.42.35.14:5601/built_assets/dlls/vendors.bundle.dll.js:427:136329
requestLoaded@http://10.42.35.14:5601/built_assets/dlls/vendors.bundle.dll.js:427:135225
```

[image]

Comment: Does the user have read permissions on the index? Just dashboard permissions alone are not enough

Comment: Thanks xeraa, your solution work like a charm,

Comment: Great. I've added it as an answer so we do it the proper StackOverflow way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the user have read permissions on the index? Just dashboard permissions alone are not enough; this is unfortunately not super obvious.

The user (or role) needs to have at least the read permission on the desired index in addition to the dashboard-only role.

Check the documentation here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-dashboard-only-mode.html#grant-read-access-to-indices

BTW the feature has generally been reworked and is deprecated in the old form

Comment: And how is that done? I mean, giving these read permissions using the Kibana GUI. I don't really understand the logic behind this process. You set up a very obvious role: "kibana_dashboard_only_user", but then it has to be further configured in a completely non-obvious way...

Comment: There are two different things at work: `kibana_dashboard_only_user` limits the features of Kibana. The permissions of the index manages the data itself. The docs are pretty explicit about this: vhttps://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-dashboard-only-mode.html#grant-read-access-to-indices BTW the feature has generally been reworked and is deprecated in the old form.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. I have updated the answer with your info, which I think is quite useful.